# How to pass dynamic value into Javascript Function?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, this code works fine

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This is question.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" 

width="42" id="showHideImg" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="showHide">This answer.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("showHide").style.display=="none")
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide").style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide").style.display="none";
    }
}

</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

However, in the real app, I got many images & `<p>` like the followings:

```
<p>This is question1.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" 

width="42" id="showHideImg" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="showHide1">This answer1.</p>

<p>This is question2.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" 

width="42" id="showHideImg" onclick="myFunction()">
<p id="showHide2">This answer2.</p>

.......question 3... 4....5...
```

My question is that how to modify the `myFunction()` so that it can dynamically apply for many `images`

I tried like the following:

```
<p>This is question1.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" 

width="42" id="showHideImg" onclick="myFunction(1)">
<p id="showHide1">This answer1.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction(var no) {
    if (document.getElementById("showHide"+no).style.display=="none")
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide"+no).style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide"+no).style.display="none";
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Check your console. You have a syntax error. Don't declare parameters with `var`. You should only have `no`, not `var no`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `var` when declaring your method arguments.

Try the following:

```
function myFunction(no) {
    if (document.getElementById("showHide"+no).style.display=="none")
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide"+no).style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide"+no).style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it in, leave off the `var`, and you're done.

I'd refactor out a bunch of stuff though, and make names meaningful, e.g.,

```
function toggleEl(num) {
    var el = document.getElementById("showHide" + num)
      , currStyle = el.style.display
      , nextStyle = curr === "none" ? "block" : "none"
      ;

    el.style.display = nextStyle;
}
```

(Note that `toggle()` may be sufficient for your ultimate needs.)